# Как отформатировать число с точкой?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, форматирование

Как преобразовать число с точкой в текст, например если `10523,20` сделать `10 523,20` или если `12252025,23` сделать на `12 252 025,23`.

Для примера, сейчас делаю так:

```
  lbl1.Caption := floattostr(10523.2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [FormatFloat](http://www.delphibasics.ru/FormatFloat.php):

```
lbl1.Caption := FormatFloat('### ### ###.00', 123234.4534534) // 123 234,45
```